# How to achieve 2 pass encoding using x264?

Tags: c++, h.264, video-processing, x264, libx264

is there a parameter in the x264_param_t structure 
or do I have to send frames to x264 dll twice.. ? 
Because I just use encoder_encode function and that returns nal units .
Im guessing it should be a combination of a parameter and using encoder_encode twice.

Here is how i initialize params and link to libx264

```
    InitializeSettings(){
    x264_param_default_preset(&m_pXParam, "medium", "zerolatency");
    x264_param_apply_profile(&m_pXParam, "baseline");
    m_pXParam.i_width = cx;
    m_pXParam.i_height = cy;
    m_pXParam.i_fps_num = fps;
    m_pXParam.i_fps_den = 1;
    // rate control
    m_pXParam.i_keyint_max = fps - 5;
    //m_pXParam.rc.f_rf_constant_max = fps + 5;
    // rate control
    m_pXParam.rc.i_qp_constant=18;
    m_pXParam.rc.i_qp_min=18;
    m_pXParam.rc.i_qp_max=18;}

    x264_picture_alloc(&m_xPicture, X264_CSP_I420 , m_pXParam.i_width, m_pXParam.i_height);
    m_xPicture.img = x264img;
    m_iframe_size = x264_encoder_encode(m_xEncoder, &m_xNals, &m_iNal, &m_xPicture, &m_xPictureOut);
```

@nobody555 Thanks! I had another question about x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass function:

```
/* x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass:
 *      If first-pass mode is set (rc.b_stat_read == 0, rc.b_stat_write == 1),
 *      modify the encoder settings to disable options generally not useful on
 *      the first pass. */
```

what options are they talking about ?

Answer (score 1):

To do 2pass encoding you will need to pass all video through libx264 twice. First pass with param.rc.b_stat_write = 1 and second pass with param.rc.b_stat_read = 1. Also you can specify stats filenames param.rc.psz_stat_out / param.rc.psz_stat_in if you don't want to use default value of "x264_2pass.log".

Comment: And what does that have anything with 2 pass? Use the version you want to. If you want to use a newer version link to the newer library when building your program.